# Where is the documentation for the Emoro GLAM pro module?

Tags: documentation

My 11-year-old son recently brought out an Emoro robot he got for his birthday. We had some temporary confusion with the robot, but got it to work.
He is now trying to connect to his computer via Bluetooth from the Emoro, but cannot find any documentation on Emoro Bluetooth.

Where is the documentation for Emoro Bluetooth?

Answer (score -1):

What you are searching can be found via googling, if you know, what to google for. I write a formal answer to this, because there is neither a link on the product page of the manufacturer, nor is it very easy to find for a beginner.

Have you seen [this repository `emoro-2560-library` on github](https://github.com/inovatic-ict/emoro-2560-library)? It seems to incorporate libraries for nearly ever function of the Emoro, including the bluetooth functionality of the GLAM board. You can find examples in the GLAM examples folder.

How did I found it? I googled for "emoro github". A better search phrase would be "emoro 2560 github" (Since Emoro 2560 is somewhat the extended name of the robot). I used the term "github", since most libraries for Arduinos and their derivates/variants are hosted on github. If you are search for a library, you can first search for them on github. Most times you will find something. Often these libraries also serve as a kind of documentation (as real and good documentation can be rare to find).

---

Now somewhat unneeded, but from the library code and the pictures on the product page of the GLAM module, I think, that a serial bluetooth module with AT firmware like HC-05 is used. If you ever want to look past the bluetooth library for the robot, you would need to go that way. (How a Hc-05 is controlled can also be googled)

Comment: the library is in Library Manager and has some Bluetooth named files

Comment: Ah, I didn't look in the library manager. But this answered the question, so I guess it is ok.

Comment: it is a very strange library. it duplicates the files from the Arduino core

Comment: The question was about _documentation_. I already have the _library_ installed.

Comment: @nerdguy If you want more documentation then what is in the library, the only ways are to google or to ask the manufacturer/reseller. And it an very well be, that the robot is just not good documented.

Comment: the Emoro core contains the Bluetooth code. the repository link to GitHub in the answer is not a valid core or library